# I use jquery for search text but my image is not show too. I need show image too

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

`

```
<input type="text" id="myInput2"  placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-lg">


<div class="container">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="tab-content col-lg-offset-0 " id="myDIV2">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="page1">
                  <a href="kohlarn.html">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                      <div class="thumbnail"
     <img src="img/sea/Koh Larn/3.jpg" alt=" Koh Larn" class="img-responsive" >
     <div class="caption">
      <h3 class=""> Koh Larn <p style="font-size: 0%;"> Koh Larn </p></h3>
      <p>text </p>
                          <div class="btn-toolbar text-center">
                            <a href="kohlarn.html" role="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Details</a>
                        </a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                    
      </div>
    </div>



 <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myInput2").on("keyup", function() 
          var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
          $("#myDIV2 *").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
          });
      });
  });
  </script>
```

`

my code can find text but my image not show too when I search. How to code for show text and image in div

this jquery code I copy from w3school

I try changes code .text() is .show() or add .fadeIn() before .text(). it can't work
I expect solve this code for show image and text in div when I search

thankyou for help me help beginner code

Comment: Please note you haven't closed your div `<div class="thumbnail"
     <img src="img/sea/Ko`

Comment: You are also missing `{` after `("keyup", function() `. With all these errors, you need to take it a bit slower and make sure your code is "correct". With the javascript error you should have seen an error in code.

Comment: Also why do you expect the img to be shown? It don't have any "text"

Comment: As above, take things a bit slower, understand what your code is doing and why - ideally learn to step through / debug.  You mention w3school[s] but don't provide a link - it could be that the source has a very specific use and you're trying to apply it to a more general use.   For example `$("#myDIV2 *")` seems unlikely to be what you actually want as it will look through nested elements as well.

Comment: my text is Koh Larn

Comment: Try changing `$("#myDIV2 *")` to `$(".tab-content")` - *might* be more of what you're expecting

Comment: sorry I didn't add link w3school link is https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_filters_anything

Comment: As *expected* on the w3schools site: `$("#myDIV *")` is used *exclusively* to actually mean `$("#myDIV > *")` because there's only one level of elements under #myDiv there - but you have multiple levels under "myDIV" so `#myDIV *" is not appropriate for your scenario.  Your scenario only shows 1 element under #myDIV2, so the use of "filter" is superfluous - if you could add additional HTML to show how you might have multiple tab-contents, it would help provide you with something for your scenario.

Comment: I tried changing $("#myDIV2 *") to $(".tab-content") already, as you advised.
And finally, it works!

Really thanks all your helps here. Really appreciate it.  
@freedomn-m; @CarstenLøvboAndersen Løvbo Andersen